# Two variable in a plot Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

[image]

I have two calculation result

```
x1 = if ((o1-c1)/c1)*100 > input
    1
```

```
x2 = if ((o2-c2)/c2)*100 > input 
    2
```

I would like to have a plot with those two variables together like

```
plot (x1 & x2)
```

So the result will be 12 or 1 or 2
but I can't find out how to replace the "&" to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to swap your conditions in:

```
//@version=4
study("")
// c1 = ((o1-c1)/c1)*100
// c2 = ((o2-c2)/c2)*100
c1 = close > open
c2 = close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1]

x1 = c1 ? input(1) : 0
x2 = c2 ? input(2) : 0
x3 = (x2 != 0 ? x1 * 10 : x1) + x2
plot(x1, "x1", linewidth = 1)
plot(x2, "x2", linewidth = 2)
plot(x3, "x3", linewidth = 3)
```